# Trouble redirecting to a method belonging a child's table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actioncontroller

I have two tables, one child of the other:

```
resources :events do
    resources :invitations 
end
```

How can i reach the path:/events/:event_id/invitations/new specifying the parameter event_id in a method inside invitations controller?

Comment: Which method in the controller.  Do you have an `event` object already in the method?

Comment: there are two cases: 
in the first, i want to call the action new of invitations controller after the creation of new event 
secondly, i want to call another time the action new of invitations controller to handle multiple invites.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a console you can use the following rake task to view the routes configured within your app:

```
rake routes
```

In there, you'll find something along the lines of:

```
    event_invitations GET      /events/:event_id/invitations(.:format)           invitations#index
                      POST     /events/:event_id/invitations(.:format)           invitations#create
 new_event_invitation GET      /events/:event_id/invitations/new(.:format)       invitations#new
edit_event_invitation GET      /events/:event_id/invitations/:id/edit(.:format)  invitations#edit
     event_invitation GET      /events/:event_id/invitations/:id(.:format)       invitations#show
                      PUT      /events/:event_id/invitations/:id(.:format)       invitations#update
                      DELETE   /events/:event_id/invitations/:id(.:format)       invitations#destroy
```

From this, you can see that there is a `new_event_invitation` route, which accepts an `event_id` and sends the request to the `#new` action of the `invitations` controller.

Assuming you have an `@event` which you'll be creating an invitation for, you can use this in an erb view as a link like so:

```
<%= link_to 'Create invitation', new_event_invitation_path(@event) %>
```

There's lots more information about routes in the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: i've just created an event through a form and i'd like to reach  :/events/:event_id/invitations/new inside events#create. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can simply use a redirect in your controller. Make sure you capture the event you create, and then pass it to the path helper like this: `redirect_to new_event_invitation_path(event)`

Comment: If this has answered your question correctly, then you should mark it as such.